# CSS: Centering 2 images horizontally, and giving them a margin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap to build a template for a project, and i need to center some social icons, here is an image:

[image]

Now, i have some JS that decides if i need to append 1 or 2 social icons, incase of 1 icons, i just want to center it, incase of 2 icons, i want to center them next to eachother with a small margin.
Is this possible with CSS alone?

In the image, i just applied a margin-left, and since they are floating left, this aligns them somewhat, but this is not responsive, and it doesnt support a single image.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row social_row">
    <img class="social_icon" id="facebook_share" src="assets/images/social/facebook.png">
    <img class="social_icon" src="assets/images/social/pinterest.png">
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.social_row {
   margin-right: 15px;
   margin-left: 15px;
}

.social_icon {
  height: 45px; 
  width: 45px; 
  display: block; 
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-align:center` the row (`.text-center` class I believe with Bootstrap) and then put left/right margins on the `img`.

http://bootply.com/88212

```
<div class="row social_row text-center">
    <img class="social_icon" id="facebook_share" src="assets/images/social/facebook.png">
    <img class="social_icon" src="assets/images/social/pinterest.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.social_row img {
    margin:0 2.5%;
}
```

Comment: They could also use `:first-child` which works for IE7 and up.

Comment: Actually, the `:first/last-child` was unnecessary. Updating answer now.